# How do I not allow typing in a text input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard, keydown

I am using the jQuery datepicker on a text input field and I don't want to let the user change any of the text in the text input box with the keyboard.

Here's my code:

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').keydown(function() {
  //code to not allow any changes to be made to input field
});
```

How do I not allow keyboard typing in a text input field using jQuery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').keydown(function() {
  //code to not allow any changes to be made to input field
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Does this cover paste events?  What if I click in the box, and type ctrl-V ?

Comment: Use keypress instead of keydown. keypress will still allow tab, ctrl-v, etc. etc. while keydown blocks all keys.  @Cheeso, I may be 5 years late in answering your question, but.... I answered it!

Answer (score 6):

You could simply make the field read-only with:

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

If you're using jQuery 1.6+, you should use the `prop()` method instead:

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').prop('readOnly', true); 
// careful, the property name string 'readOnly' is case sensitive!
```

Or ditch jQuery and use plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('rush_needed_by_english').readOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: No, that would make the field look disabled also and I am trying to avoid that. I just dont want them to be able to type.

Comment: ANother problem with attribute disabled these fields will not get passed to server